# Encapsulating parameterised prefabs

Tags: unity, architecture, design-patterns

I'm currently using the following general pattern for most of my configurable components (i.e. `MonoBehaviour`s):

```
public class MyComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Configurable fields
    [SerializeField]
    private bool someParameter;
    [SerializeField]
    private int anotherParameter;

    // Fake constructor to act as a replacement for GameObject.AddComponent
    // with additional parameters.
    public static MyComponent AddTo(GameObject gameObject, bool someParameter, int anotherParameter)
    {
        var myComponent = gameObject.AddComponent<MyComponent>();

        myComponent.someParameter = someParameter;
        myComponent.anotherParameter = anotherParameter;

        return myComponent;
    }

    // Public properties and other methods
    // ...
}
```

This works around the lack of constructors for `MonoBehaviour`s but still encapsulates the parameters in such a way, that they can only be set at the time the object is created, or through the Inspector (which is effectively the same thing once the game is built).

Unfortunately, this approach doesn't help once I want to use my component inside a prefab. When I instantiate the prefab, the component has already been created, and I can no longer touch those parameters. And as far as my google-fu can tell, there's no way to pass parameters into prefab instantiation (much like there isn't a way to pass a parameter into `AddComponent`). It seems like everyone just instantiates their prefabs and then fiddles with some public properties to configure them.

So the question is, is there any way to set things up, such that I can configure some fields on my prefabs, but *without* exposing them publicly and breaking encapsulation?

(I realise that I could add a similar static "factory" method which instantiates a specific prefab and then configures the component inside that prefab, but a) this means adding one such method for each prefab and b) it breaks down once I want to configure multiple components within the same prefab.)

Comment: Looks like a good [factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to me. And sounds like you need a Factory factory...Because Unity's [entity-component system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93component%E2%80%93system) is not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

A naive (simple) approach would be to simply have an object which encapsulates the state you want and store it in a static field, then access that field in `Awake`.

```
    public class MyComponent : MonoBehaviour {
      [SerializeField]
      private bool someParameter;
      [SerializeField]
      private int anotherParameter;

      public class InitInfo {
        public readonly bool someParameter;
        public readonly int anotherParameter;
        public InitInfo(bool someParameter, int anotherParameter) {
          this.someParameter = someParameter;
          this.anotherPatameter = anotherParameter;
        }
        void Apply(MyComponent c) {
          c.someParameter = someParameter;
          c.anotherParameter = anotherParameter;
        }
      }
      public static InitInfo OnAwake;

      //note: you may be able to use the constructor instead of Awake,
      //but you must not interact with Unity in any way (eg instantiating
      //other objects, modifying the
      //transform, adding other components, calling Mathf.Random,
      //etc.) because this may be called on another thread.
      //Assigning a few fields should be fine though. 
      //public MyComponent() {

      void Awake() {
        if (OnAwake != null) {
          OnAwake.Apply(this);
          OnAwake = null;
        }
      }
    }
```

and elsewhere:

```
  MyComponent.OnAwake = new MyComponent.InitInfo(true, 5);
  Instantiate(myPrefab);
```

Although this breaks down if you want to configure multiple instances of the same component type within the prefab. I’m not sure if that’s what you were referring to when you were talking about configuring multiple components?

Other options include using `BroadcastMessage` to send the information in after instantiation is complete, or a callback where the caller registers a special method to be called in `Awake`, passing in the current component, and returning the data necessary, although these are just variations on the same theme.

For example:

```
    public class MyComponent : MonoBehaviour {
      [SerializeField]
      private bool someParameter;
      [SerializeField]
      private int anotherParameter;

      public class InitInfo {
        public readonly bool someParameter;
        public readonly int anotherParameter;
        public InitInfo(bool someParameter, int anotherParameter) {
          this.someParameter = someParameter;
          this.anotherPatameter = anotherParameter;
        }
        void Apply(MyComponent c) {
          c.someParameter = someParameter;
          c.anotherParameter = anotherParameter;
        }
      }
      public static Func<MyComponent, InitInfo> OnAwake;

      //public MyComponent() {
      void Awake() {
        if (OnAwake != null) {
          OnAwake(this).Apply(this);
        }
      }
    }
```

and elsewhere:

```
  int i = 0;
  MyComponent.OnAwake = c => new MyComponent.InitInfo(true, i++);
  Instantiate(myPrefab);
  MyComponent.OnAwake = null;
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess this sort of works, but you're right that it doesn't work if the component appears multiple times in a single prefab, and I also wonder whether this amount of boilerplate code is actually worth it. Plus, I'd have to make sure I always set and unset the `OnAwake` correctly, which seems a bit unsafe, although I guess I could wrap that entire 3-line instantiation in another static method to avoid that. This is good food for thought though, I'll think a bit more about whether I can turn this into something more feasible.

Comment: Also, doing the actual initialisation in `Awake` is interesting. It's too bad you can't do anything between `Instantiate` and `Awake`, but if I can defer setup until `Start`, I could just have some public properties which are copied over to private fields on `Start` and then never used again. That would also provide a way to configure the object without being able to mess with it afterwards.

Comment: Actually, I *can* intercept the `Awake` call, provided I make sure the prefab itself is inactive.

Comment: Actually, I _think_ there is a call between Instantiate and Awake, which is the constructor. It does still get called, although it may happen on a different thread. If you’re just passing in some types to apply to fields this shouldn’t matter.

Comment: Also note that my second suggestion does allow for multiple instances in the same prefab.

Comment: Oh yeah, it allows for multiple instances, but what I mean is I couldn't configure them differently, they'd all end up with the same values. As for the constructor, I've read that one should stay clear from it, because it can get called multiple times, and the real problem is that I can't actually call it myself from outside to pass in the values. Deactivating the prefab before instantiation should work to intercept `Awake` though, so I'll give that a go.

Comment: My second suggestion is specifically designed to allow you to configure them separately with different values, because it passes in the instance to configure. If you had a way to differentiate them, such as a public field set in the inspector that you can inspect in the callback, for example, where each instance has a different value, then you can construct the InitInfo based on that.

Comment: Ahhh, neat, I missed that part.